# Use Automator to get content of text files in finder

Tags: macos, automator

I'm trying to create an automator-app which I can drop a finder-folder in it. It needs to filter all (thousands off) txt files and pass the contents to "Text to Audio File"

But the only available action is Get Contents of TextEdit document, and this is the currently open TextEdit document.

Is there no way to just get the content of an selected document? I think that's quite a common usage?

Comment: I might submit an alternative solution but I would like to clarify whether you want the _Automator_ workflow to be passed a folder containing lots of text files; or a selected document or documents?  Or, perhaps, either?

Comment: Also, what audio format would you prefer the files to be in ?  Finally, can you give a snippet of sample text that contains the non-US characters ?

Comment: Also, what audio format would you prefer the files to be in ?  Can you give a snippet of sample text that contains the non-US characters ?  Finally, is one text file intended to produce one audio file (so you end up with thousands of audio files); or are the text files being merged to create a single audio file ?

Comment: @CJK the most preferred workflow would be to select a folder in finder, and then "right click->services->Convert2Audio. The folder should be scanned for txt-files, and then one by one converted to AIF and then imported into iTunes as audiobook as AAC.

This is what I have now [1]: https://imgur.com/a/lggGmNs.png

Each file should be 1 audio file (chapter).

Comment: OK, that's actually really easy to do using a bash (shell) script inside an _Automator_ service.  The importing to iTunes can be done either with _Automator_ actions, or through AppleScript.  Let me throw an answer together and I'll hopefully demonstrate how this can be done.  Any preferred voice ?

Comment: @CJK Bash, That'd be great. I thought I was stuck to automator because of the "Text 2 audio" command. Shell is much easier and faster. (having the filename before the _ as the album name and set the imported audio as an audiobook would make the workflow perfect)

Comment: What "_" ?  I think you're assuming I know what your filenames look like, which, of course, I don't (and your `.png` didn't work).  Also, got a snippet of text using the non-US characters ?  Need to make sure we don't get text encoding issues.

Comment: @CJK I was thinking out loud actually. If it's possible to copy the filename to clipboard as the current applescript does, I can parse the part in front of it as a new variable to use in the iTunes Song Info.


Here's the imgurlink again [link](https://imgur.com/IYTSiSO) and here's the link to the file [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hsetmkgxgm98zmx/%E5%85%AB%E9%9B%B6%E5%90%8E%E4%BF%AE%E9%81%93_v9.txt?dl=0) and here's a snippet 

`code`
马道长。那不是比人贩子更可怕。马五郎不说还好。一说。张叫花哭得比刚才还要伤心了。倒不是马五郎这个人有多凶神恶煞。而是这村子里的幼教的功劳。平时哪个小屁孩不听话了。爷爷奶奶爹娘就会说：马道长来了。你还哭。被马道长捉去当小鬼。所以在小孩子的心目中。最可怕的人。人贩子是排第二位的。马道长才是排第一位的。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel this particular problem is more well suited to bash scripting than AppleScripting overall, given the sheer number of files you'll be dealing with, and the need to convert their contents to spoken audio.

Here's a screenshot of the *Automator* workflow I came up with, which I believe addresses all of your needs and wants:

[image: Automator workflow on macOS High Sierra]

The two scripts (shell script and AppleScript) are reproduced at the bottom of this answer for simple copy-n-pasting, but the content of each is fully visible in the screenshot.

### Overview

This workflow is designed to operate as a **service** in *Finder*, which will let you select a folder, right-click, and run the workflow from the pop-up context menu.  You can also assign a keyboard shortcut to it.

The folder is passed into the workflow.  Its contents is retrieved, which provides the workflow with a list of files inside the folder.  These are sent into the shell script.

The shell script navigates into the supplied folder and creates a subfolder called `"Audio"`, in which the audio files will be saved.  Then it loops through every file in the supplied folder.  If the file is not a `.txt` file, it is passed over.  Otherwise, the command line tool **`say`** is used to convert the contents of each file to a spoken audio track.  I selected a voice for it that speaks Mandarin ("Sin-ji").  The data format used for the audio files is `aac`, which avoids having to do a second conversion in *iTunes* later.  The file format uses the file extension `.m4b`, which may seem unfamiliar, but is essentially an `aac` file encapsulated in an `mp4` wrapper, with the file extension altered in line with Apple's recommendations.  The `.m4b` extension tells macOS that the audio file is an *iTunes* audiobook (other ones Apple uses are `.m4a` for regular audio, and `.m4r` for ringtones).  The cool thing about using the `.m4b` file extension is that, when it's imported into *iTunes*, it's instantly recognised as being an audiobook, and placed in the audiobooks section.

The shell script returns the path to the `"Audio"` directory, now populated with audiobook files.  The workflow retrieves the contents of this directory, i.e. the audiobook files, and imports them into *iTunes* without doing any further conversions.  They get sent straight to the library, and end up in the audiobooks section.

Here's the annoying bit: it seems that when *iTunes* imports new files into its library, it temporarily places a lock on the files, presumably as the files are copied across, the files scanned, and the metadata are written.  During this time, setting any properties of the new imported tracks is not possible, and results in a "File permissions error".

The duration will vary from system to system, and probably on the number of files imported as well.

Inserting a pause into the workflow of 5 seconds gave the files sufficient time to be unlocked on my system, before proceeding to the final AppleScript.

As per your request, this AppleScript's only job is to use the part of the filename that comes before the underscore (`"_"`) to name the album, and that's what it does.  If the file tracks are all unlocked by this point, it'll do it beautifully.  If any one of the tracks are still locked, it'll cause the script—and the workflow—to throw an error.

(Oddly, putting in an error handler to catch the errors and prevent it from halting the script also seemed to prevent the properties from being set.  There's something buggy happening in *iTunes* AppleScript, but this doesn't surprise me.)

---

### Scripts

#### Shell (bash)

```
    cd "$(dirname "$1")"      # Go into supplied folder
    mkdir -p "Audio"        # Create a folder for the audio files
    cd "Audio"

    shopt -s nocasematch    # For case-insensitive regex matching

    for f in "$@"; do        # Loop thru files; txt → m4b (audiobook)
        fn=$(basename "$f")
        [[ "${f##*.}" =~ txt ]] && \
        say --voice=Sin-ji \
            --output-file="${fn%.*}.m4b" \
            --input-file="$f" \
            --file-format=m4bf \
            --data-format=aac
    done

    pwd                     # Return the present working directory
                            # i.e. the "Audio" folder
```

#### AppleScript

```
    use application "iTunes"
    property text item delimiters : "_"

    on run {input, parameters}

        repeat with m4b in the input
            set m4b's album to text item 1 of (m4b's name as text)
        end repeat

    end run
```

---

### Download the workflow

Finally, I've uploaded the *Automator* service workflow for you to [download](https://transfer.sh/9EP3x/Convert2Audio.workflow.zip), saving you having to recreate it all from scratch.  It should be available for the next 30 days.

Comment: Wow! that's simply insane. Much more than I've asked for! Thank you very much for it. Although I can't open the automator workflow in automator (it crashes with an error), it does work as intended. I'll recreate it just to learn though.

Getting this errorr when opening
`Application Specific Information:
Performing @selector(_openRecentDocument:) from sender NSMenuItem 0x6080002b0c20
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<SBObject 0x60c000e55b10> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.'`

Answer (score 0):

In Automator, add a “Run AppleScript” action to your workflow  and insert this following AppleScript code into that  “Run AppleScript” action.

Basically the code will take the currently selected file in Finder, and if the currently selected file has a name extension of “txt”, it will pass the content of that text file into your next workflow action,which would be… Text To Audio File

```
tell application "Finder"
    set theSelectedFile to (get selection)
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    set nameExtension to name extension of (theSelectedFile as alias)
    set fileName to name of (theSelectedFile as alias)
end tell
if nameExtension is "txt" then
    set theContent to read (theSelectedFile as alias)
    set the clipboard to fileName as text
else
    return
end if
return theContent
```

[image]

Next you will create a new AppleScript variable and insert it into the “Save As” field in the “Text To Audio File” action.. Using the values `theName` and `set theName to the clipboard` as shown in the screenshot above.  Doing this will set the name of your newly created audio file to the name of the original source text file

Comment: That's great! but it seems theContent is not working for non-us characters. If I output it as a new text file instead of audio file, I get this...

Êñ∞‰π¶ÂàöÂºÄÂßã„ÄÇÊ≤°ÊúâÂ≠òÁ®ø„ÄÇÊØèÂ§©Â∞ΩÈáè‰øùÊåÅ‰∏§Êõ¥

Comment: Every reference to `theSelectedFile` sees it being coerced to an `alias`.  Perhaps it’s more sensible to do that during its declaration: `set theSelectedFile to selection as alias`.  Of course, your script will throw an error if more than one file is selected, as `selection` will return a list.  _Finder_ can also get `name extension` and `name` properties, so switching to _System Events_ when you were already in a _Finder_ block is odd.

Comment: I would have perhaps done: `tell application "Finder" to tell item 1 of (selection as list) to set [selectedFile, filename, nameExtension] to [it, name, name extension]`.  This retrieves all the properties in one go, and won't throw an error because of multiple selections.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to do this using an action of type "Run Shell Script"

Then the single command `cat /path/to/your_desired_file.txt`

This passes the contents of the file on to the next action.

Hope that helps!